# Ajax load json file with funny chars not working in IE

Tags: ajax, json, special-characters

I am having problems with ie. In the json formated file I have:

,{"id": "33","re": "Maranhão"},{"id": "33","re": "Mato Grosso"},{"id": "33","re": "Mato Grosso do Sul"},{"id": "33","re": "Minas Gerais"},{"id": "33","re": "Paraíba"},{"id": "33","re": "Paraná"},{"id": "33","re": "Paro"},{"id": "33","re": "Pernambuco"},{"id": "33","re": "Piauí"},{"id": "33","re": "Rio de Janeiro"},{"id": "33","re": "Rio Grande do Norte"},{"id": "33","re": "Rio Grande do Sul"},{"id": "33","re": "Rondônia"},{"id": "33","re": "Roraima"},{"id": "33","re": "Santa Catarina"},{"id": "33","re": "São Paulo"},

FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera no problem. IE having problems with the special characters.

After doing a lot of searching someone that seemed to have the same problem got told to add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

So thats what I did but still no go. Here is my code. Obviously it works. Adding just in case.

```
function GetRegions(CoID)
{
    var i=0;

    $.ajax({      
        type: "GET",      
        url: "http://localhost/JSONFiles/cregions.json",      
        async: false,      
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(data){     
            $(data).each(function(){
                if (this.id==CoID)
                {                   
                    if (i==0)
                    {
                        $('#st_Region').find('option').remove(0).end().append('<option value="0">Select Your Region</option>').val('0');                        
                    }               
                    i++;
                    $('#st_Region').append('<option value="'+this.re+'">'+this.re+'</option>');
                };
            });             

            if (i==0)
            {
                $('#st_Region').find('option').remove(0).end().append('<option value="1">No Regions For This Country</option>').val('1');                                   
            };
            i=0;
        }

    });
};
```

Any help would be creatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Content type for JSON as `"application/json"`

Also, add an error function and see what the error is. This should take you to the error directly.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(textStatus);
    // you can add different alert here to check
    alert(errorThrown);
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
}
```

Also, why do you end your `if blocks` with a `;`? Though it won't result in error( as `;` is **a legal empty statement**), it might introduce `undesired features` and cause headache.

Comment: OK I did what you sugested: TEXTSTATUS:parsererror , ERRORTHROWN: Invalid JSON: Then it gives the whole file. I know the file is valid because if I take the special characters out it works fine.

Comment: Which special characters are you talking about?

Comment: It is an assumption. If you look at the json snippet above you will see region names like "São Paulo"

Comment: I LOVE THE INTERNET!!! I FOUND THE SOLUTION: http://jsonlint.com/ It checks your file and then changes all special characters "São Paulo" becomes "S\u00e3o Paulo". Works GREAT!!!. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't look the code, but your string is not JSON valid. Trim that commas at start and end and wrap all in [ ]

```
[{"id": "33","re": "Maranhão"},{"id": "33","re": "Mato Grosso"},{"id": "33","re": "Mato Grosso do Sul"},{"id": "33","re": "Minas Gerais"},{"id": "33","re": "Paraíba"},{"id": "33","re": "Paraná"},{"id": "33","re": "Paro"},{"id": "33","re": "Pernambuco"},{"id": "33","re": "Piauí"},{"id": "33","re": "Rio de Janeiro"},{"id": "33","re": "Rio Grande do Norte"},{"id": "33","re": "Rio Grande do Sul"},{"id": "33","re": "Rondônia"},{"id": "33","re": "Roraima"},{"id": "33","re": "Santa Catarina"},{"id": "33","re": "São Paulo"}]
```

Comment: That was just a partial copy and paste the data is wrapped in []

Comment: Also just mention that it DOES WORK in FF, Opera etc. No problem. Just IE giving me the Sh^&s.

Comment: It is an assumption. If you look at the json snippet above you will see region names like "São Paulo"